# PHP - How do question marks after address work?

Tags: php, url

I've been wondering what links like http://example.com/filename.php?dosomething and http://somesite.net?logoff do.

As I don't know much about PHP, and english isn't my native language, I've been unable to find  good information like this.

I know that http://mysite.com/edit.php?editpassword and http://mysite.com/edit.php?editname could serve totally different content, but how can I implement it?

Let's say that I want to implement these lines of code to ?editpassword

```
Password
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
```

and these lines to ?editname

```
Type your name
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
```

How could I do it in a file that could contain

```
<?php 
require "includes/head.php"; 
require "includes/nav.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>



            <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">New</li>
              <li><a href="#">sss</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span9">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span9">
              <h2>Some header</h2>
              <p>Some text</p>
            </div><!--/span-->
          </div><!--/row-->
          <div class="row-fluid">
            ?editname & ?editpassword should appear here.
      </div><!--/row-->

            <?php require "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's just `?foo` the whole querystring which is available in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is `"foo"`.

When using a HTML form with `method="GET"` you get key-value pairs which are then available via `$_GET['key']`. Actually you also receive those pairs when using POST but then they are not visible in the URL and you access them via `$_POST['key']`.

---

So your code would look like this assuming you want it totally simple and not use some advanced routing framework:

```
switch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    case 'editname':
        // do stuff
        break;
    case 'editpassword':
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do stuff if none of the cases matched
}
```

**But I'd really suggest you to use proper GET variables instead of just plain query strings.** Simply replace the first line of that snipped with this:

```
$action = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';
switch($action) {
```

Comment: *But I'd really suggest you to use proper GET variables instead of just plain query strings.*

Answer (score 3):

Anything passed after the URL using `?` is essentially a 'query string'. The variables passed in are accessible inside of PHP through the `$_GET[]` superglobal.

Let's say in your example, you passed in `editname` and `editpass` sepratrely. You can then handle this using the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['editname']))
{
    // handle edit name code here (i.e. show form, etc.)
}
elseif(isset($_GET['editpass']))
{
    // handle edit pass code here
}
?>
```

Failing that, you can also use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` array value, which will return anything that appears after the `?`. If you're going to be working with lots of different possible query strings, it might be better to use a `switch()` statement:

```
switch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
{
    case 'editname':
        break;

    case 'editpass':
        break;

    default:
        // i.e. no query string.
        break;
}
```

Sometimes, you might need to pass in more than one variable in the query string, in which case the vars are delimited by `&`. You can also assign values to the variables using the usual assignment operator (`=`). So for example, consider the following URL:

`view-user.php?id=1&action=view`

We can then access `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['action']` inside of `view-user.php`, and handle everything as required.

Comment: Using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is not the best option to teach to beginners. Better use `$_GET['']` and  `$_POST['']`.

Comment: Well, the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the complete  URL parameters string. Your switch statement checks the entire combination and order of URL parameters to equal (of of the) the listed switch values. So if the URL parameters appear in a different order (which is offcourse completely correct) your swith statement example does no longer function. This can be confusing, and is seldom what a beginning programmer is looking for.

Comment: When you're passing in a single string (as the OP posted), it is irrelevant, and sometimes the best solution. I did offer the best practice when using more than 1 parameter. Of course, you should read the whole question, and use which solution best fits. Your comment that it's not the best option is kind of redundant.

Answer (score 0):

All values after the questionsmarks are http-get-parameters. You can check if they are set using `if(isset($_GET['login'])) {}`. You can also assign to those parameter values by using parameter=value.

Answer (score -1):

The `?` marks the first URL parameter. You can add additional URL parameters with the use of `&`.

the URL `http://example.com/index.php?foo=1` Will result in

```
// index.php
echo $_GET['foo']; // outputs: 1
```

The URL `http://example.com/page.php?foo=2&bar=baz`

```
// page.php
echo $_GET['foo']; // outputs: 2
echo $_GET['bar']; // outputs: baz
```

Keep in mind that the `&` in (X)HTML is (correctly) written as `&amp;`, because it is a reserved character.

So, a complete example index.php:

```
<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
        echo 'link was clicked '.$_GET['foo'].'x<br>';
        if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
            echo 'foo is '.$_GET['bar'].'<br>';
        }
        $url = 'index.php?bar=world&amp;foo='.($_GET['foo'] + 1);
    } else {
        $url = 'index.php?foo=1&amp;bar=hello';
    }
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">click me!</a><br>';
?>
</body></html>
```